# Jquery ajax call with '+' sign

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

```
$.ajax({  
        type: "POST", url: baseURL+"sys/formTipi_azioni",data:"az_tipo="+azione,
        beforeSend: function(){$("#form").html('<p><img src="'+baseURL+'lib/img/ajax-loader.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" /><p>');},
        success: function(html){$("#form").html(html);}  
     });
```

there is a case when azione is

```
TB+
```

the plus sign doesn't get POSTed at all, a blank space get sent. I already tried this:

```
azione = escape(String(azione));
```

With no luck. Does anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
azione = escape(String(azione));
```

should be

```
azione = encodeURIComponent(String(azione));
```

or simply

```
azione = encodeURIComponent(azione);
```

Comment: Type-casting doesn't work like that in JS... (`(String)azione`)

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST", 
    url: baseURL + "sys/formTipi_azioni",
    data: { az_tipo: azione },
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#form").html('<p><img src="'+baseURL+'lib/img/ajax-loader.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" /><p>');
    },
    success: function(html){
        $("#form").html(html);
    }  
});
```

and leave jQuery do the url encoding for you.

Comment: Nice, I never knew this was possible. Thank you.

Comment: It is possible and the benefit is that you don't have to worry about url encoding.

Comment: +1, best solution in this context. "Never use `escape()`" is still a point to keep in mind.

Answer (score 9):

*Never* use `escape()`. Use `encodeURIComponent()`.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying to compose the post data yourself, you can also let jQuery do the work by passing it an object:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST", url: baseURL+"sys/formTipi_azioni",
    data: {az_tipo: azione},
    beforeSend: function(){$("#form").html('<p><img src="'+baseURL+'lib/img/ajax-loader.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" /><p>');},
    success: function(html){$("#form").html(html);}  
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

you are looking for [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 2):

```
escape(String(azione)).replace(new RegExp( "\\+", "g" ),"%2B");
```

this one sends the plus symbol with the help of regular expression