# The form dont include the + sign, that i write

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code will submit the information from the form to a php file, everything works as it should, but when i write "hello this a text + - * " it remove the " + " sign from what i wrote, always. I dont know why, please help me out guys

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form#submit").submit(function() {
        // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
        var fname     = $('#fname').attr('value');
        var lname     = $('#lname').attr('value'); 

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Mail.php",
                data: "fname="+ fname + "&lname=" + lname,
                success: function(){
                    $('form#submit').show();
                    //$('form#submit :input').val("");
                    $('div.success').fadeIn();
                }
            });
        return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery ajax call with '+' sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022867/jquery-ajax-call-with-sign)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `fname` and `lname` are text boxes, why not use the `.val()` to retrieve them?

```
var fname = $('#fname').val();
var lname = $('#lname').val();
```

or better, use form `.serialize()` directly on the ajax:

```
$(function () {
    $("form#submit").submit(function () {
        var form = $(this)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Mail.php",
            data: form.serialize() //turns the form data into a query string
            success: function () {
                $('form#submit').show();
                $('div.success').fadeIn();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Change this line:

```
data: "fname="+ fname + "&lname=" + lname,
```

to:

```
data: "fname="+ encodeURIComponent(fname) + "&lname=" + encodeURIComponent(lname),
```

You need to escape special characters for use in URL strings.

Comment: I tired to change it, like you say, but nothing changed

Comment: You could leverage more on jQuery's ability to perform escaping for you :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the pluses are converted to spaces. Use `encodeURIComponent` to escape the input. **Always** use some kind of escaping to avoid injections.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: $(this).serialize()
    ...
});
```

This takes all the :input elements inside your form and encodes them properly for sending to a remote server. You could also do this:

```
data: {
    fname: fname,
    lname: lname
}
```

jQuery understands that you're trying to send an array of values and will automatically escape it.

Btw, this is not very portable:

```
var fname = $('#fname').attr('value');
```

The better way is this:

```
var fname = $('#fname').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var email = $('#email').val();
var data = 'email=' + encodeURIComponent(email);
var url = 'test.php'
var type = 'post'
var success = function(output){}
var error = function(){}
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:type,
            data:data,
            success:success,
            error:error
        });
```

work great for me